# Building a docker image doesnt stop because of minecraft server continuing to run

Tags: java, docker, minecraft

So I have been trying to learn docker for a few days now and set a first goal for me.
I want to run a spigot server inside a docker container and later on the road combine that with a BungeeCord network.
I have run into problem.
My dockerfile runs without problems but once it reaches the point where it starts the minecraft server, the images stops building.
I think this is due to the server continuing to run and not returning a code 0 to show docker to keep on running.
Am I wrong with my idea, and if not, how can I fix the problem?

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install openjdk-7-jre icedtea-7-plugin -y
RUN apt-get install wget -y
RUN mkdir mc_server && cd mc_server/
RUN wget http://getspigot.org/spigot18/spigot_server.jar
RUN java -Xms1536m -Xmx1536m -Dcom.mojang.eula.agree=true -jar spigot_server.jar nogui
```

This way the server starts up but docker never finishes building.
I hope I made my problem clear.

Greetings,
Joel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace that last `RUN` with `CMD`.

`RUN` / `ADD` / ..  are used to build the static container environment where you want to run your application in. Everything that happens before running the actual application.

`CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` define what's supposed to happen inside the container once you `docker run` it. This is where the startup script / call goes for the program.

The result of the `Dockerfile` is similar to a computer that's shut down but has everything installed on the harddrive including a script that autostarts the application. Turn it on and everything starts to run.

PS: https://hub.docker.com/search/?q=spigot&page=1&isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&starCount=0&pullCount=0 there are several existing images